# ssh2 timed out while waiting for handshake in nodejs

Tags: node.js, ssh

I am trying to upload a file using ssh in my nodejs application, while trying, I am getting error as **"connection error: timed out while waiting for handshake".**  gave connection setting as,

```
....
}).connect({
   host: 'hostname without http',
   port: 22,
   debug: console.log,
   readyTimeout: 99999,
   username: 'name',
   password: 'password'
 });
```

If I upload manually to the server it is working fine with the given hostname, username and password.

Comment: It is usually nice to list the error messages in a code style section separately.  For your question, the process running your program may not have a login account.  Or password access disabled on the ssh server.

Comment: "upload manually" isn't very descriptive, what does that mean?

Comment: "upload manually" - when I tried to upload the same file directly in the browser with the same username and password. it's working fine.

Comment: Got the same problem, seems like a authentication timeout issue?